# HTTP connection to GCE hangs after initial connection

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an debian instance with a network firewall that allows for web traffic (tcp:80,443).

On that instance, I have set up Nginx and Rails unicorn with very standard configs. When I hit the server from my browser to retrieve a static file, GCE would return that file instantly with no problems. However, if you leave the server idle for 5 mins or so, and try hitting the *same* URL/file, the request would hang for about 5-7 mins before it returns. In the meantime,  other URLs would return instantly, just not the URL that I had retrieved earlier. The hung request would eventually return after 5-7 mins.

I checked the logs and Nginx and Unicorn seem to get the request, but the response seems to be lost somewhere in the network. I suspect that the GCE might be doing some caching that expires after some amount of idle time and that is causing the long-delay in the 2nd response.

I have narrowed the problem to GCE since I recreated the same stack on non-GCE VMs and they all worked as expected. (Btw, the standard configs include turning off ALL caching on Nginx and Unicorn)

Am I missing a config that I'm supposed to set?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with Apache/Jetty server.  What I just did was create a really annoying loop to wakeup the server. What I guess happens is the server sleeps and the initial un-responciveness is the server waking up. What I have now is index.html redirects to redirect.html which redirects to my Java app. By the time the first two files are hit the App is up and running ready for use.  Kinda hackey and primitive. If anyone has a better solution i'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

the gce documentation mentioned issues with the keep alive
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#communicatewithinternet

we have the same issue with our servers too. 
going to implement the recommended settings and monitor it for a day or 2.